# JQuery disabling, and clearing other checkboxes, besides one labled "All"

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, html-table

I am refactoring an existing checkbox selector. The first option is an "All", and following are individual selections. I would like to, if "All" is selected, disable the other options from being selected. If "All" is not checked, the other selections become available, and, if any individual selections are checked, then the user selects "All," the code will clear the other ones out, and disabling them.

I am new to jQuery, but have been able to target the functionality when "All" is selected, on both 'click' and when the page loads.

```
<table id="ctl12" class="dynCheckBoxList">
<tr>
    <td><input id="ctl12_0" type="checkbox" name="ctl12$0" checked="checked"/><label for="ctl12_0">All</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input id="ctl12_1" type="checkbox" name="ctl12$1"/><label for="ctl12_1">BN</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input id="ctl12_2" type="checkbox" name="ctl12$2"/><label for="ctl12_2">C2</label></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input id="ctl12_3" type="checkbox" name="ctl12$3"/><label for="ctl12_3">CC</label></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and for my JQuery

```
if ($('#ctl12_0 input[type=checkbox]:checked')) {
    alert('yup');
}

$('#ctl12_0').on('click', function (){
    if ($('#ctl12_0').is(':checked')) {
        alert('yup');
    };
});
```

I'd also like to refactor this JQuery. I had to write two separate sections of code. The If statement will fire because the "All" selector is checked when the page loads, but the following function will fire each time (after page load) when the user selects it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$("#ctl12_0").change(function() {
    var inputs = $("[id^=ctl12]:checkbox").not(this);
    this.checked ? inputs.prop({disabled: true, checked: false}) 
                 : inputs.prop("disabled", false);
}).change();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/YYrkj/1/